# Getting the url of a Facebook Image using Graph API v2.5

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make something like a facebook feed inside a Ionic App, but i want only the pictures that a specific fan page is tagged.

I'm doing something like this:
    `GET   /v2.5/{{pageId}}/photos?type=tagged`

In JavaScript:

```
       ngFB.api({
    path: '/811154709006505/photos',
    params: {type : 'tagged'}
   }).then(
   function (res) {
     console.log(res);
   },
   function (error) {
      alert('Facebook error: ' + error.error_description);
   });
```

But it only returns me the created_at and the photo ID and Description. In Graph API v2.3 the returned a "image" value with the "source" field inside. Can I use the 2.3 version? Or its possible to do this in v2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Just needed to pass what I wanted lol

```
ngFB.api({
 path: '/811154709006505/photos',
 params: {type : 'tagged',
         fields : 'id,name,source,created_time'}
}).then(
```